# Get JSON data from PHP using Javascript:

Tags: javascript, php, json

In my javascript I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0, at
>   JSON.parse (), at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange

when trying to receive some stuff from a PHP script. 
I've seen some similar questions but I couldn't find a solution for my case.

> My server PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

> My client javascript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        var s = req.responseText;
        var users = JSON.parse(s);
        console.table(s);
    } 
}
req.open("GET", "./get_info.php", true);
```

When I run the PHP file using the browser I get this:

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

which I believe is correct.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use your browser's "Network" developer tab to inspect the actual response to the HTTP request.

Comment: In the Network tab the response is "Parameter missing"

Comment: this should work fine as it stands, it shows a valid json string. there's definitely something fishy on the response or you're not showing the whole php

Comment: This is more or less the example provided by W3Schools but something is wrong. Any suggestion on how to find/track the problem?

Comment: in case you forgot, initialize the object `$myObj = new stdClass;` at least

Comment: Well that "Unexpected token" is the "P" at the beginning of "Parameter missing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code is working fine**, you could check if you are getting any warning in php response which cause an error in JSON.parse at client side, meanwhile same error I got while running your script in my system.
**Getting Response from php -**

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/tst/get_info.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

**At Client Side :**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange
```

**Fixed this issue by disabling the warning in my php code -**

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```